# Как изменить версию Python по умолчанию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, launcher, pylauncher

Установил `python-3.13.0a4`. При установке убрал галочки `Path` и `Установить Launcher`.
С путями `PATH` все нормально, ведут к каталогу версии `3.12`, с Launcher в папке Windows тоже, `py.exe/pyw.exe` оба остались версии `3.12.2150`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... но `powershell`, `cmd` и `bash` запускают версию `Python 3.13.0a4`:

```
PS py -V
=> Python 3.13.0a4
```

Как заменить параметры запуска по умолчанию на стабильную версию `3.12`?

Comment: Насколько я помню, это дефолтное поведение лончера _без параметров_; он запускает либо питон из активного окружения, либо последнюю версию какую найдет (не обязательно в пределах PATH). Чтобы запусть первый пайтон из PATH, нужно вызывать `python` а не `py`.

Comment: @Vitalizzare `python -V` действительно указывает на `3.12`, но хотелось бы настроить `py`. Уже прочитал в доках, что это можно сделать через `py.ini`, вот не могу понять куда его лучше положить.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft [пишет](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/faqs#what-is-py-exe-), что `py.exe` запускает по умолчанию последнюю версию.

> Странно, я предполагал, что `launcher 3.12`, не должен повышать
> версии. Это не так!!!

Python Docs [пишет](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#customization-via-ini-files), что `launcher` так же будет искать файлы `py.ini`.

В общем в `C:/Users/<USER>/AppData/Local` надо положить файл `py.ini`:

```ini
[defaults]
python=3.12
```

... теперь работает.

UPD: Дополение из коммента от @Vitalizzare

В документации говорится об эквиваленте файлу путем установки переменной `PY_PYTHON`. Переменная имеет приоритет над файлом, можете добавить, если нет желания использовать файл(тоже работает):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что если определить в своем окружении [PY_PYTHON](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#customizing-default-python-versions)?

Comment: @Vitalizzare Да, и это работает. Поэкспериментировал - переменная оказывается имеет приоритет. Добавил в ответ. Спасибо за поправку.